# Lenovo touchpad becomes very slow in random intervals on Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, touchpad, lenovo, lts

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu on my Ideapad 3. The touchpad was working fine but then after a while, I noticed it became very slow and hard to move in random instances and then it went back to normal. I also faced this exact problem on Kubuntu too, I'm on a Lenovo Ideapad 3 15ITL6 machine, and my Ubuntu version is 22.04 LTS

After installation of the OS, I have only done 1 thing that may contribute to this problem:

I changed the trackpad settings and made it faster.

Thank you guys